# select query with multiple tables in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, resultset

hey guys,
i have 3 tables in my sql server database.
1. crossarticle_article has field: Title
2. blogs_entries  has field: title
3. forums_posts.  has field: subject

now what i want to do is, i have a search on my website, when user enters any keyword in the searchbox and hit button, it should search for the title in all these table and should return single resultset.

how can i achieve this, i am using sql server 2008

Comment: Write the 3 queries and combine them with `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT "article"                  AS type
     , crossarticle_article.id    AS id
     , crossarticle_article.Title AS title_subject
FROM crossarticle_article 
WHERE Title LIKE "%userinput%"

UNION ALL

SELECT "blog entry"               AS type
     , blogs_entries.id           AS id     
     , blogs_entries.title        AS title_subject
FROM blogs_entries
WHERE title LIKE "%userinput%"

UNION ALL 

SELECT "forum post"               AS type
     , forums_posts.id            AS id
     , forums_posts.subject       AS title_subject
FROM forums_posts
WHERE subject LIKE "%userinput%"
```

Answer (score 1):

A [`UNION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) will return unique results, whereas a [`UNION ALL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) will return everything including duplicates.

```
SELECT Title
FROM crossarticle_article
WHERE Title = '%term%'
UNION
SELECT Title
FROM blogs_entries
WHERE Title = '%term%'
UNION
SELECT subject AS Title
FROM forums_posts
WHERE Title = '%term%'
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Title
FROM crossarticle_article
WHERE Title = @Title

UNION

SELECT title
FROM blogs_entries
WHERE title = @Title

UNION

SELECT subject
FROM forums_posts
WHERE subject = @Title
```